# xamarin forms distinct objects sort based on the no of times that they appear

Tags: forms, list, sorting, xamarin, distinct

I have made an Xamarin forms application and the problem that I have a list named lista2 which has an object named poli. Poli is the city that it is located. I want to make a list based on distinct cities, which i have done using this command

`var poleislist = lista2.Select(x => x.poli).Distinct();`

now I want this poleislist to be sorted based on the amount of times that each element is on the lista2. For example the bigger cities appear more often and I want them in the first places of the list because this list(poleislist) is going to be the itemsource of a picker.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Distinct` you could `Group` the list, sort it by count descending then `Select` the `poli`.

It would be something like this:

```
var poleislist = lista2.GroupBy(item => item.poli)
                       .OrderByDescending(a => a.Count())
                       .Select(x => x.Key)
                       .ToList();
```

Note: sorry did not get to test it but this should work. Basically this should get you all the cities in the list, ordered descending by the number of times it appears.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: thank you it seems that it is working but when I run the application with this command: selectPoli.ItemsSource = poleislist.ToList(); (where selectPoli the picker) it shows me this error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Do you have any ideas what is causing this error?

Comment: it it throwing that exception because poleislist is null

Comment: Yes, one of the items of the list was null and it was throwing that exception. Thank you very much again!